# Thread model for playing external SWFs inside an SWF?

Tags: multithreading, flash, animation

I am designing an application that allows users to use animated emoticons(defined using external SWF files) and display them inside another SWF file.  This works as long as there are only a very small # emoticons at a time, but if the number increases significantly the performance starts to slow to a crawl....  The bottleneck isnt the network as there are only a few emoticons to choose from, we are just having issues displaying them simultaneously.

How does the Flash threading model handle playing external SWFs?  Can we attempt to play them on a separate thread, or will that cause issues(like it does in Swing and Cocoa and the like)

Answer (score 0):

its hard to say, when you mean loading multiple small swf , are they copies or are you creating new instances, with new properties etc...

I have managed to similar thing making a 20 line poker machine that uses swf for all the images, animations . These files each are about 600Kb and there is 12 of these at one time on the screen animated(well depends on the win);

But how i did this was load them into an array every time i needed it. and access it from there. i didnt seem to have any issues.

Its not much of an answer but can you explain your loading method, or put a sample html  server i could see whats exactly your problem